# What is this tiny, transparent creature found in my home?

Tags: species-identification, species

[image]
[image]

Found these in my bathroom, everything was literally crawling with them - there were thousands of those on walls, sink, bathtub... I have all surfaces were sprayed with chlorine spray and with bug repellent afterwards. Still these creatures came back same day, although in smaller numbers.

There's not many features I can use to describe this creature aside from:

- Size: very tiny, below 1mm; *(black strands are beard hair)*
- They are pale-yellowish and semi-transparent as it's seen on photos provided
- Rather slow and they walk aimlessly on all kinds of surfaces
- They **seem** to be coming from cupboard under the sink, where it's warm, moist, dark and there's access to sewage piping shaft

I'm aware photos could be much better, but they were taken with smartphone combined with a lens from a flashlight to enable macrophotography. Not a best tool for that purpose though.

EDIT: Added circles around creature. Please ignore zoom cursor on first image.